# I have read multiple sources on the IMM filter but I cannot understand how to implement it

Tags: kalman-filters

I am working on an image detection and tracking problem and have correctly implemented the Kalman filter. I have two Kalman filters and want to track a maneuvering target. After all the books I have read, no one uses a solved example or an easy to understand way of implementing at least one cycle of the system. Can someone here help in correctly implementing the filter?

Comment: Which books have you read?

Comment: If Matlab source code suites for you then here's one implementation : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38534-imm-filter

Comment: @Arnfinn I have read estimation with applications to tracking and navigation, optimal estimation of dynamic systems and the kalman filter book by Roger laabe which exists as a jupyter notebook. However,i cannot understand the logical steps through which I can implement the IMM tracker.